# Azure SQL set default Collation

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

The default collation for Azure SQL is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, not too good if your language has accents or diacritics and you want to ignore them. Everytime I want to deploy a web application with database to Azure I'm forced to create the database manually and set the collation in that moment. If this database needs to be dropped for any reason I have to keep in mind that it has to be created manually again to set the collation and the price level.

I would like to use the Entity Framework Core methods for creating from scratch the database and set the collation from there (EnsureDatabaseCreated and Migrate), but I think this is not possible at the moment and, given the speed the Entity Framework is being developed it probably won't be until year 2035.

So, the best solution is setting the default collation on the server instance (so the new database created on it would get this default) but there is no option when you create it... I know this can be done for a "normal" SQL Server instance but, does anybody know if it is possible for a SaaS Azure SQL Server instance? If so, how?

Comment: when you create a  database in azure,you can see the ARM template for that..which is collection of json values,to help you in creating the db automatically next time,check if that is helpfull to you

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Entity Framework creates the database atuomatically, the thing is "tweaking" the server to get the databases created with a different collation than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you **cannot** change the collation of the Azure SQL DB Server - only the database.

That said you can can use [EF to run a T-SQL Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) to [change the collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx) of the Azure SQL DB by running something like this:

USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest
COLLATE French_CI_AS ;
GO